# Well-ordering of sets of cardinal numbers

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, cardinals

> **Proposition** For every cardinal number $m$ there is a definite next larger cardinal number.

This proposition is proved on page 136 of "Proofs from the Book" using the fact that any set of ordinal numbers is well-ordered. However the latter fact is presented without proof.

The reasoning looks kind of strange to me because it seems that we are proving the well-orderedness of any set of cardinal numbers by means of the same property for sets of ordinal numbers. (And I have a feeling that the proof for ordinals should be even harder than that of cardinals, but I must be wrong!)

I don't have any background in set theory or logic, but I was hoping someone could either direct me to a "non-technical" reference or perhaps share some insights on this. Thanks!

Comment: The ordinals are well-ordered essentially by definition.  The real content here is the assertion that you can represent all cardinalities using ordinals.

Comment: @EricWofsey To be fair, it depends on what definition you use. If "ordinal" means "hereditarily transitive set," then it's definitely not just by definition.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend one of two books for you to learn about the foundations of set theory,

Proofs and Fundamentals by Ethan D. Bloch
Topology by James B. Munkres

Comment: In this context, the *natural numbers* are $0, 1, 2, \dotsc$. In any case, your 2nd paragraph is very conjectural and not enlightening: OP said nothing about $\omega$ (the natural numbers); the statement holds for *any* cardinal. The usual proof uses the [Hartogs number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) of the cardinal, and does *not* use choice.

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestions, William. Just wanted to emphasize that my question is not about proof writing in mathematics, but rather about something quite specific about ordinal and cardinal numbers. (I took a look at the first book and it does not cover ordinal numbers at all!)

Comment: The foundation of proof writing in mathematics is a strong understanding of the theory of sets. The book is called "proofs and fundamentals," but it covers the foundations of the theory of sets. Munkres is a more advanced treatment. I would suggest you read these two books to get a strong foundation for how to manipulate functions, sets, and relations. Then you will be able to write a good proof yourself.